# Windows 7 Dual Monitors in Duplicate display mode - How to set zoom just one monitor?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, display, zoom

I have dual monitors set to duplicate the display on both. Is it possible to zoom in on one monitor but not the other?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "zoom"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of Duplicate mean "the same thing".  So this is not possible without defying logic.

One method to try is to extend your desktop to two monitors and maximize the built-in Magnifier on the other monitor.

Comment: I managed to fullscreen the magnifier window on one monitor.